# Expandable content of UITableViewCells "shines" trough

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I just made a `UITableView` in swift with expandable cells when clicking them. Upon being expanded, the cells show a `UIDatePicker`.

The expanding itself works fine, but the cell-content that should only visible when the cell is expanded kind of shines through the cells. Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about:
[image]

**Cell 1 is expanded and the other cells are not.** As you can see, their expandable content is visible while it actually shouldn't be.

Here is the code I use:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cellIdentifier = "Cell";

    var cell: NewExpenseTableCell;
    var array: NSArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil);

    cell = array.objectAtIndex(0) as NewExpenseTableCell;
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();

    cell.descriptionLabel?.text = descriptionLabels[indexPath.item];

    return cell;
}

var selectedRowIndex = -1;

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if selectedRowIndex == indexPath.row {
        selectedRowIndex = -1;
    } else {
        self.selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row;
    }
    newExpenseTable.beginUpdates();
    newExpenseTable.endUpdates();
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex {            
        return 206;
    }       
    return 55;
}
```

Could anyone tell me how I can make sure the `UIDatePicker` is **only visible when the cell is expanded?**

Comment: It looks like a cell reuse issue. Do you have a subclass for `NewExpenseTableCell`? If you do, please show its code. If not, where do you set `hidden` property for its `UIDatePicker` subview?

Comment: No I don't have a subclass of NewExpenseTableCell, it just extends UITableView Cell.

I do not set the hidden property anywhere. Where should I set it?

Comment: There are several possible approaches. You can create a subclass for `NewExpenseTableCell`. Then change the `hidden` property on a date picker in `setSelected:animated` method and also set `hidden` to `NO` in `prepareForReuse`.

Comment: It partly works now, but it creates some kind of flickering. I also now thing that the issue might be reuse-related. Is there a proper way of how to reuse custom-made UITableViewCells (which are loaded from .xib file)?

Comment: Try to use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` method in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates`, it might help with flickering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would recommend to get the cell reuse working correctly.

1. Open the .xib file for your NewExpenseTableCell. Go to Attributes Inspector, enter "NewExpenseTableCell" as the Identifier.
2. In the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller, register the nib like so:

   ```
   self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "NewExpenseTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "NewExpenseTableCell")
   ```
3. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, replace the first four lines you have with this:

   ```
   var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewExpenseTableCell") as NewExpenseTableCell
   ```